# jQuery: How to check when all images in an array are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, onload

I have an array of images (the exact number of images varies), and when they all load I want some code to execute.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
myImgArray.load(function(){
    alert('loaded');
});
```

I get

> 33: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'load'

I don't think a for loop or something similar would work because the images might, and probably will, load in 'random' order.

Comment: I wonder how you have constructed that array. What does it contain?

Comment: @robert Basically I look for all <img> elements in a certain div and push them into an array.

Comment: Whey don't you use jQuery: `$('#divId img')` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way I know of to do it is to attach a load handler for each image and keep a count of how many have been loaded.  When you reach your total, then they've all been loaded.

Here's code that does that:

```
var urls = [
    "http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-Ti.jpg",
    "http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344292111_SvSfK-Ti.jpg",
    "http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291168_nErcq-Ti.jpg"
];

var imgs = [];
var cnt = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ++cnt;
        if (cnt >= urls.length) {
            // all images loaded here
        } else {
            // still more images to load
        }
    };
    img.src = urls[i];
    imgs.push(img);
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7KF7V/

For this to work, the `onload` handler function has to be assigned before the `.src` property is set because if the image is in the browser cache, onload may fire immediately before `.onload` is assigned, thus missing the event.